# Language Changer for the textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for the plugin/code which allows me to select the language option and while user entering data into text-box it will change the language

also what to allow this functionality for only some input option
means if there is 3 text box then only 1 or 2 will work after language change rest will allows English by default

**Without refreshing the page after language is selected**

Comment: What do you mean by changing the language? The language of the keyboard? Spell checking?

Comment: @Nippey look there is 1 section list where the 2 languages are defined English and Hindi if I select Hindi then into the textbox it allows me to type Hindi not an English 
have you got it?

Comment: Aah, right. Okay I was thinking in the wrong direction, but I can't help you with this problem. Good luck!